# Guzzle request with public/private keys

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to build a Guzzle request in Laravel to connect to an API with a public/prvate key, and I keep getting a 401 auth error...

Here is my code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.myprivateurl.com/api/']);
    $response = $client->get("accounts/$account", ['headers'=>['DefaultPublicKey'=>'PublicKey', 'DefaultPrivateKey'=>'Private Key']]);
    echo $response->getBody();
```

And here is their documented requirements:

private const string BaseUri = @"https://api2.tigerpawsoftware.com";

private const string DefaultAcceptHeader = "application/xml";

private const string DefaultPublicKey = [Public Key];

private const string DefaultPrivateKey = [Private Key];

I've been searching the Internet forever, and I'm completely lost. (I can get the Github API working fine though!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send auth credentials in the url:

```
$response = $client->get("accounts/$account", [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
    ],
    'query'=>[
        'DefaultPublicKey' => 'PublicKey', 
        'DefaultPrivateKey' => 'Private Key'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks - but unfortunately still get the same error...It says <string>Invalid user name or password.</string> - however I have confirmed with the API developers that there is no username and password required...